# Bootstrap 5 - Place Radio Buttons Inline and a Radio Input Group next to each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

"Simple" problem, I'm trying to place a few radio buttons(inline) and a radio input group next to each other, on the same line. For some reason the input group goes to a new line.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-none" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">none</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">filter 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">filter 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter">
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
    </div>
</div>
```

[https://codeply.com/p/DAlKhU9atE](https://www.codeply.com/p/DAlKhU9atE)

Thanks

Comment: Remember, code needs to be in the question itself.. "The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." external links tend to change over time rendering the question useless to future readers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `flex-wrap`. Use `text-nowrap` to prevent wrapping labels...

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-none" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">none</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-1">
        <label class="form-check-label text-nowrap" for="inlineRadio2">filter 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-2">
        <label class="form-check-label text-nowrap" for="inlineRadio2">filter 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter">
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/UZMwQv2hXR)

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard Bootstrap grid. Like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-none" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">none</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">filter 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter" id="filter-2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">filter 2</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radioFilter">
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`col-auto` auto-sizes the div to only take up as much space as needed. You can change that to just the other `col-` classes as needed to get the exact widths you want. See the Bootstrap documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid